# How to declare conditional resource in serverless framework

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework

I use typescript definition of serverless configuration (serverless.ts). How do I conditionally add resources using cloud formation templates ?
For example AWS cognito userpools, if I want to exclude these for offline mode, how can I specify it in serverless config file to not include them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it 2 ways. [serverless-plugin-ifelse](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-ifelse) allowed me to exclude resources based on certain parameters.

Later I realized this may be problematic in the long run. So I created separate serverless config file for my offline use case to include all necessary resources. Prod/Staging environments used default serverless.ts file. Offline uses offline-serverless.ts file. Though there is some repetition of the resources config, this option ensures prod/staging config is not polluted with offline content. I could start offline using `sls offline start --stage local --reloadHandler --config offline-serverless.ts`

And the offline config reuses some code from main config. Sample offline-serverless.ts content is below:

```
    import offlineplugins from "offlineplugins";
    import pluginsconfig from "offlinepluginsconfig";
    import plugins from "plugins";
    
    const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
      service: "my-offline-apis",
      frameworkVersion: "3",
      ...pluginsconfig,
      plugins: [...plugins, ...offlineplugins],
      provider: {
        name: "aws",
   ....
   ....
```